# How to set hidden attribute in QGIS Lyon?

Tags: qgis, fields-attributes

I want to set my attribute as `hidden` in `QGIS`.

I have tried Layer Properties -> Fields -> text edit -> Select Hidden. It is just information.

> In hidden attribute will be invisible - the user is not able to see
>   it's contents

How to set hidden attribute?

Answer (score 3):

What you did is the correct way to hide the field. 
In the widget menu select the `hidden` value, then press OK.
[image]
Then you should see the label `Hidden` in the field attribute column named `Edit Widget`
[image]

Apply and close the layer properties window. 
If you still see the field you hid in the layer attribute table, close it and open it again, it should be gone now.